# Laravel and unit testing, mocking data

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

I have the following controller:

```
class ProjectController
{
    public function __Construct( IProjectRepository $projectRepo )
    {
        $this->projectRepository = $projectRepo;
    }

    public function ListWithPagination()
    {   
        $projects = $this->projectRepository->Paginate( 2 );
        return $projects;
    }
}
```

And the following model/repository:

```
class EloquentProjectRepository implements IProjectRepository
{
    public function Paginate( $amount )
    {
        return Project::paginate( $amount );
    }
}
```

**1. How do I mock data to place into this test?:**
I don't want to use the actual Projects in my database because there may not be enough projects to test... But also that I may want to make sure the 2nd page's first Project is indeed the one I expected it to be.

```
/**
* Check that pagination amount returned is as expected.
*/
public function testCheckPaginationAmount()
{
    // Setup
    // Mock 3 Project items... Make sure 2 come back from page 1.

    // Act
    $response = $this->action('GET', 'ProjectController@ShowList');  

    // Assert
    $this->assertGreaterThan( 2, count( $response->getContent()[ 0 ] ) );   
}
```

**2. How could I mock the $amount that has been passed into that Paginate function in the controller**

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should unit test your repository (e.g. with phpunit) and use the database for that test you wrote.

Comment: This is using PHPunit Do you have examples of the code?